# Raspberry Pi Zero 2W in gadget mode with USB HUB HAT

Tags: hat, gadget

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero 2W in gadget mode that can transmit data and emulate a mouse or keyboard.

But when I connect a USB HUB HAT, I'm not able to transmit data. I'm getting `[Errno 108] Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown`.

Is there a way I can be able to send data while having USB HUB HAT connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to know which USB HUB HAT you're using, but all the ones I've seen use the USB data port, either directly plugging into it (eg [waveshare](https://www.waveshare.com/usb-hub-hat.htm)) or via pogo pins (eg [Zero4U](https://www.uugear.com/product/zero4u/)). In both cases the pi has to run as a USB host to the USB hub, it's just different ways of connecting to the trace on the PI.

You can't run in gadget mode and host mode at the same time